# How to kept Chinese character in mind?

Tags: characters

Hi I'm new to Chinese language and i'm getting hard to kept Chinese character.

Every time i learn new character I forgot the previous one. One of my friend advice me to learn the origine of every character.

Please can someone share a method that helped to do so. Maybe good books or videos.
thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Chinese StackExchange. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic, as learning methods work differently for different people, so any answer will be primarily opinion-based. If you have a particular character that you want to know the origins of, you can ask that in a separate question.

Comment: It's true but i asked for the help in the meaning to redirect me to some good articles so i can learn the origins and everything related to Should not I ask so @droooze cause i'm new here ?

Comment: Shood I remove the question ? @droooze ?

Comment: You can ask questions about [learning methods for Chinese](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-methods+chinese) on Language Learning Stack Exchange. You can flag your own question for migration (instead of deleting it here and reposting it there), but please make sure that you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and some of the other topics in the help centre of that site.

Answer (score 2):

1. Start with basic characters. Complex characters are consisting of the basic ones.
   I found it it very helpful to learn the Japanese kanji kentei level 10 characters first (without reading/pronunciation of course)
2. Repeat drawing them and stick to the stroke order. 90% of the success is practise. I do not mean one time 2hr practise , but consistent practise over months and years. Every week two or three times is much more efficient, after all you are learning in the long term.
3. Make up your own mnemonics (using the basic characters)
4. I like to draw the characters in a rather high quality notebook instead of using scrape paper because I can see the progress and how the book becomes full, fills me with pride. A good occasion imo is while watching a movie.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is marked as off-topic, it still can be friendly if we offer a few answers for novice, even they're opinion-based.
The hardest point for foreigners (except Japanese, Koreans and overseas Chinese) to learn Chinese, is the Chinese script. They are far more complex than any alphabetic and syllabic scripts, and the pronunciation of characters cannot be deduced using a simple rule (different from any language other than Japanese, but Japanese do use kanas).
I don't know if there should be a separate method for you all, but I can still recall the time we Chinese learn our own language at the age of seven to eight. We learned Pinyin at first, and at that time even texts in textbooks were written purely in Pinyin. As we could master all pronunciations, we would start learning characters, from numerals like 一, 二, 三 to more complex ones. Note that even mastering our own language could take years to decades.
It changes now: primary school students will try to learn some simple characters first to get a feeling about mother tongue, then move to Pinyin about a year later. In my opinion, this is not as efficient as the previous way for foreigners, since they will be easily lost in the forest of logographies. I personally recommend our traditional way of learning: learn to speak first, then write them down.

Answer (score 1):

We can actually divide a single chinese character into several parts, and one of them is the "radical" , it is usually on the left side of the character, like the left three lines of 浓 which is the water radical, or the two lines of 位 which is the man radical and both of them are related to the actual definition of the character. 
 The second method, is to think of the character as a picture. 高 means high, and it actually might look like a tall structure. But be careful, because this will only work for simple ones.
 Hope these methods could help you!

Answer (score 1):

i am actually working on a game which will help learners to keep in mind Chinese characters, as they are used for playing :-)  You can get a few photos there :

https://fr.ulule.com/youdao-dayou/ In that game, Character cards describe the composition with components and radicals as it is judiciously mentioned in the first answer :-)

Sorry that explanations are using French language :-(

Comment: Oh nice I wish i'll be the first one who play this game :D. I'm good in french no pb :).

Comment: Thank you to support :-) Actually find players in true life is hard. You know Kotlin ? where do you live ? please take a look to 打有 on FB :-)

Comment: We did studied a unit last year about kotlin and i did some small exercises in Kotlin. I'm from Algeria. You can find me on facbook always same name Dina Taklit.